# Assertion Failed Error with same outputs

Tags: java

I have a class that parses a .json file and I am trying to write test code for the parser method.

Here is my test code, the expected and result are the same as you can see by the trace log.

```
@Test
public void testParse() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("parse");
    String fileName = "data/fake-1.json";
    RedditListingParser instance = new RedditListingParser();
    ArrayList<RedditThing> expResult = new ArrayList();
    RedditThing thing = new RedditThing("85osel", "ONE TWO TWO THREE THREE THREE", "JoseTwitterFan");
    expResult.add(thing);

    ArrayList<RedditThing> result = instance.parse(fileName);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

And here is the stack log

```
expected: java.util.ArrayList<[85osel, JoseTwitterFan, ONE TWO TWO THREE THREE THREE]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[85osel, JoseTwitterFan, ONE TWO TWO THREE THREE THREE]>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at reddithottopicsanalyser.RedditListingParserTest.testParse(RedditListingParserTest.java:55)
```

I'm not sure what the exact problem is here as I can implement a test to check whether it is null and that does that test without a problem.

Thankyou.

Comment: Maybe an unprintable character in the file?

Comment: Do you have the RedditThing.equals() overridden? If no, create equals() properly.

Comment: Probably you did not implement `equals` (and `hashCode`) in your class  `RedditThing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing object references when it comes to objects inside of the two lists. In order to compare the objects correctly , you need to override the equals method. In RedditThing class , add this code.

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if( !(obj instanceof RedditThing){
        return false;
    }

   RedditThing redditThing2 = (RedditThing)obj;
    return compareEquality(this,redditThing2);
 }




static boolean compareEquality(RedditThing one, RedditThing two){
    //Compare attributes of two objects here and return true/false depending 
      // on comparison
}
```

Then you can call

`assertEquals(expResult, result);`